# Disable boot on plug in power cable

Tags: boot, power

I'm owning a Rasperry Pi3

I want to disable automatic boot when plug in power cable. I don't want to use a simple mechanic switch because I want passive power still avaible for the board for various reasons.

I couldn't find a solution. I wouldnt' have had any problems soldering stuff because I already added a power button for shut down/restart the pi

Comment: I have seen a hardware solution: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/switch-your-rpi

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to two pins of the RUN header to keep the Pi3 in reset and thus not booting.

See [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43213/19949) where this connector is:

> The two pin "run/reset" header seems to have moved [..] to the other side of the 40 Pin GPIO connector between that and the outermost Pair of Stacked USB connectors

Function of the RUN pin explained for the Pi2 [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/29339/19949). I reasonably expect the same behaviour for the Pi3.

It is also unlikely to damage the Pi by keeping it in reset indefinitely, see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39380/19949).