# Difference between Pi3 and Pi4 RUN headers?

Tags: pi-3, gpio, pi-4, power-supply

I am trying to disable boot when pi4 plugged to power. I found some usefull [answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61588/disable-boot-on-plug-in-power-cable), but that answers are about pi 3. I am using pi 4 and I must connect together 2 RUN header pins. In pi 3 RUN header is consist of 2 holes, but in pi4 holes are three(1st is run, second is ground and third is GLOBAL_EN). Now I want to know which 2 of this 3 holes are corresponding to the same holes of pi3?

Answer (score 0):

The RUN pin on both is identical. In fact it is a SOC reset pin (which should be labeled RESET with a bar above indicating active LOW). On the Pi4 RUN is also connected to PMIC.

It is not particularly useful as it appears impossible to actually HALT the SOC in Raspberry Pi OS.

It can be used to reboot a Pi which has been shutdown but this can be done using pin 5 on the header.

If you search my answers you will find detailed discussion of the operation of GLOBAL_EN e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100234/8697